# Assign class to li based on page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu structure sitting in a masterpage, controlled by a CMS that I have no programming accessibility to besides javascript, CSS and raw HTML. It looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="Menu1.aspx" target="_self" class="active_nav">Menu Option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="Menu2.aspx" target="_self">Menu Option 2</a></li>
<li><a href="Menu3.aspx" target="_self">Menu Option 3</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

I need to change that `.active_nav` to the `li` of whatever page they are on. What's the easiest way to do this in javaScript or jQuery?

Comment: What CMS are you using? It should already identify the page you're on somehow, like a class on the body tag or something like that.

Comment: CMSs usually generate the menu with classes, what you have is hardcoded markup.

Comment: Some light CMS might not generate the menu but it sure will tell you which page you're one with an id or class or something... I mean what's the point of the CMS if you hardcode everything...

Comment: It's Kentico, and I'm being asked to provide an answer. I have no view to inside the CMS, just being asked to provide a bit of outside help. Was seeing if there was an easy way to determine page just via the DOM. Apparently that was worth voting it a -1. Too bad it doesn't show who exactly voted that way so I could have a discussion with them. To those of you who answered helpfully, thank you :)

Comment: Someone else did a -1 so I actually voted this up, as I actually think it's an interest question. I suspect someone didn't read the whole post and is unaware that you aren't able to request the information from the server. *I'd edit the title to make this obvious in case anyone else decides to vote you down :/*

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#menu>ul>li').click(function() {
    $('#menu>ul>li').removeClass('active_nav');
    $(this).addClass('active_nav');
});
```

By default, you may want to use hyphens for CSS classes. It is standard practice. This is not Python after all.

Also, this should not be done on the client side or with JavaScript. JavaScript reloads every time a user goes to a different page, which means your link will only have the active class until the browser redirects to the target location. But once the user navigates to the link of your menu item, that menu item will lose the active_nav class because JavaScript and everything else will be reloaded, from catch or otherwise, depending on your server setup.

The bottom line is that you need to do this from the server side. Basically, when rendering the page with PHP or whatever other server side language you are using, you should highlight  the current item based on the URL. This is the common way of doing things.

The only way to do it entirely in JavaScript is if you are writing an Ajax application, which means the user wouldn't actually go to a different page, but only see different content which is loaded from the server in real time. If you tell me what server side language you are using, then I'll be able to help more.

Also, Google can help, as this is an incredibly common question.

Comment: This doesn't help the OP; he makes it sound like has no way of determining what the current page is - therefore wont be able to target the correct element with this code. Furthermore, this would **give every li element in the ul the 'active_nav' class** as this selector would catch all of them.

Comment: You would expect this to be done server side, I agree - unfortunately the OP states he has no access to the server side code. **Your code would still effect every menu item; making them all 'active' as such.**

Comment: Fergus is correct, and I would go your route if I had any access to the CMS itself. So, I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Enjoy a +1 now - the edited code would be perfect for an AJAX app-type situation. *I may be a hard-ass when it comes to downvoting - but that snippet is much better!* Sorry for the initial -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

probably you need to use the current window location to know what li should be highlighted, something like this (before you must clear all active_nav classes:

```
    $('#menu a').each(function() {
      var currentUrl = document.URL;
       if (currentUrl.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) <> -1 ){
         $(this).addClass('active_nav');
       }
});
```

Regards

Comment: In the unlikely event that your CMS doesn't give you information about your current page then this is probably the best solution; besides finding a new CMS ;)